# Regext for the following

Tags: regex, google-sheets, formula

I am to get the following results as an extract from google sheets using Regex

If I have the following 2 field items:

S01_123_123_123

S02_1_123_123_123

I want to extract

S01

S02_1

I have tried the following formulas:

`=iferror(sort(unique(arrayformula(REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet!A$2:A,"^(.*?)_")))))`
This gives:

S01

S02

```
=iferror(sort(unique(arrayformula(REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet!A$2:A,"^z.*?_")))))
```

S01_

S02_

Running out of ideas now. I have even tried non grouping (?:_) with and OR "|" but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Try `^(.*?)(?:_[^_]+){3}$`

Comment: you can use `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"_\d{3}","")` to put the "extract" into an adjacent cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^(.*?)(?:_[^_]+){3}$
```

The part inside the capturing parentheses will be returned by the `REGEXEXTRACT` function.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - any 0+ chars as few as possible since `*?` is a lazy quantifier
- `(?:_[^_]+){3}` - exactly three consecutive occurrences of

  - `_` - an underscore
  - `[^_]+` - one or more symbols other than `_`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wiktor your solution worked.

```
^(.*?)(?:_[^_]+){3}$
```

If you'd be so kind to explain how that is working

Comment: You should have added it as a comment. Please removethe answer, I will add an answer.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer. If anything is still unclear let me know via a comment.